# Retrofit 2 Send array of images to server

Tags: android, image, arraylist, bitmap, retrofit2

I`m tring to send of array images to server wih other methods like  @PartMap or @Part("avatars_attributes[]"). But without result. Maybe you can help me?

For @PartMap I use HashMap with some content:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++){
                Bitmap btm = images.get(i);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                btm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
                byte[] profilePictureByte = out.toByteArray();
                final RequestBody imageBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), profilePictureByte);
                map.put("avatars_attributes[]\"; filename=\"avatars_attributes" + i + ".png\"",imageBody);
```

and

```
@Multipart
@POST(ApiRetrofitUrls.TRANSPORTS_URL)
Call<TransportEntity> addTransport(@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> map);
```

but on server received only empty array avatars_attributes[];

In another way, I use  ArrayList of RequestBody or RequestBody[],

but result is the some.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the server request contract

Comment: its post request and parameter "avatars_attributes[]" for arrays of images

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@POST(ApiRetrofitUrls.TRANSPORTS_URL)
Call<TransportEntity> addTransport(@Body RequestBody data);
```

---

```
 MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
    builder.addFormDataPart("content", textContent);

    for(String filePath : imagePathList){
        File file = new File(filePath);
        builder.addFormDataPart("avatars_attributes", file.getName(),
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));
    }

    MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
    Call<SocialCreateFeedResponse> call = mSocialClient.createFeeds( requestBody);
```